# add loading spinner for fetching api

Tags: android, kotlin

I implement get data from api server for showing marker on Google map by retrofit2, rxjava, repository. However I'm problem with making loading spinner. I do not know where I put the code for loading.

// activity.kt - show google map and show marker from api data.

```
class WaterMapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

private var mMap: GoogleMap? = null
private lateinit var binding: ActivityWaterMapsBinding
private var viewModel: MapViewModel? = null
private var listTapArea1: List<DataModel>? = null
private var listTapArea2: List<DataModel>? = null

enum class ZoomType(val type: Float) {
    WORLD(1f),
    CONTINENT(5f),
    CITY(10f),
    STREET(15f),
    BUILDING(20f)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityWaterMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MapViewModel::class.java)

    viewModel!!.getTapArea1List.observe(this, {
        mMap?.clear()

        for (dataModel in it) {
            var latLng = LatLng(dataModel.latitude!!.toDouble(),dataModel.longitude!!.toDouble())

            val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
            markerOptions.position(latLng)
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA))

            val marker = mMap?.addMarker(markerOptions)
        }
    })

    viewModel!!.getTapArea2List.observe(this, {
        mMap?.clear()

        for (dataModel in it) {
            var latLng = LatLng(dataModel.latitude!!.toDouble(),dataModel.longitude!!.toDouble())

            val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
            markerOptions.position(latLng)
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA))

            val marker = mMap?.addMarker(markerOptions)
        }
    })

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    val prefs: SharedPreferences = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("LOCATION", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val currentLat: String = prefs.getString("lat", "0.00").toString()
    val currentLng: String = prefs.getString("long", "0.00").toString()

    val currentLocation = LatLng(currentLat.toDouble(), currentLng.toDouble())
    mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation, 15f))

    // Set a listener for marker click.
    mMap!!.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
}
```

}

// retrofit instance
To use restrofit, build retrofit instance and show log by using Okhttp

```
object RetrofitClientInstance {

private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

fun getRetrofitClient(baseUrl: String): Retrofit{
    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

    val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout((60 * 2).toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout((60*2).toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout((60*2).toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .build()
    if(retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }
    return retrofit!!
}
```

}

// MapViewModel - Using viewmodel for show data from activity

```
class MapViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val mapRepo: MapRepo

    init {
        mapRepo = MapRepo()
    }

    val getTapArea1List : LiveData<MutableList<DataModel>>
    get() = mapRepo.getTapArea1lLiveData

    val getTapArea2List : LiveData<MutableList<DataModel>>
    get() = mapRepo.getTapArea2lLiveData
}

//MapService
package com.sensCup.android.waterMap

import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable
import retrofit2.http.GET


interface MapService {
    @GET("/data/listtaparea1")
    fun getTapArea1(): Observable<MutableList<DataModel>>

    @GET("/data/listtaparea2")
    fun getTapArea2(): Observable<MutableList<DataModel>>
}
```

// Repository

```
class MapRepo {
    private val mapService: MapService
    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    init {
        mapService = Common.getAPIService
    }

    val getTapArea1lLiveData: MutableLiveData<MutableList<DataModel>>
    get() {
        val data: MutableLiveData<MutableList<DataModel>> = MutableLiveData<MutableList<DataModel>>()
        compositeDisposable.add(mapService.getTapArea1()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe{postModels ->
                if(postModels != null) {
                    data.value = postModels
                }
            })
        return data
    }

    val getTapArea2lLiveData: MutableLiveData<MutableList<DataModel>>
    get() {
        val data: MutableLiveData<MutableList<DataModel>> = MutableLiveData<MutableList<DataModel>>()
        compositeDisposable.add(mapService.getTapArea2()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe{postModels ->
                if(postModels != null) {
                    data.value = postModels
                }
            })
        return data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this below way to achieve this

**In your Activity**

```
var observer : Observer<DataWrapper<MutableList<DataModel>>> =
    Observer<DataWrapper<MutableList<DataModel>>> { response ->
        if(response != null){
        
            if(response.isLoading){
                //show loader here
            }else{
                //hide loader here
            }
            
            if(response.data != null){
                //handle your data here
            }else{
                //handle your error here
            }
            
        }            
        
    }
```

**In your MapRepo class**

```
val getTapArea1lLiveData: MutableLiveData<DataWrapper<MutableList<DataModel>>>
    get() {
        val data: MutableLiveData<DataWrapper<MutableList<DataModel>>> = MutableLiveData<DataWrapper<MutableList<DataModel>>>()

        var datawrapper = DataWrapper<MutableList<DataModel>>()
        datawrapper.isLoading = true
        data.value = datawrapper

        compositeDisposable.add(mapService.getTapArea1()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({postModels ->
                if(postModels != null) {
                    datawrapper.isLoading = false
                    datawrapper.data = postModels
                    data.value = datawrapper
                }
            },
                { throwable ->
                    onErrorFromServer(throwable,data,datawrapper)
                })
            )
        return data
    }

val getTapArea2lLiveData: MutableLiveData<DataWrapper<MutableList<DataModel>>>
    get() {
        val data: MutableLiveData<DataWrapper<MutableList<DataModel>>> = MutableLiveData<DataWrapper<MutableList<DataModel>>>()

        var datawrapper = DataWrapper<MutableList<DataModel>>()
        datawrapper.isLoading = true
        data.value = datawrapper
        
        compositeDisposable.add(mapService.getTapArea2()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({postModels ->
                if(postModels != null) {
                    datawrapper.isLoading = false
                    datawrapper.data = postModels
                    data.value = datawrapper
                }
            },
                { throwable ->
                    onErrorFromServer(throwable,data,datawrapper)
                })
        )
        return data
    }



fun onError(throwable: Throwable,data: MutableLiveData<DataWrapper<MutableList<DataModel>>>,dataWrapper: DataWrapper<*>) {
    if (throwable is HttpException) {
        try {
            val response = throwable.response()
            when {
                response!!.code() == 400 -> {
                    datawrapper.isLoading = false
                    datawrapper.error = your Error
                    data.value = datawrapper
                }
                response!!.code() == 401 -> {
                    datawrapper.isLoading = false
                    datawrapper.error = your Error
                    data.value = datawrapper
                }
                else -> {
                    datawrapper.isLoading = false
                    datawrapper.error = your Error
                    data.value = datawrapper
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }else if(throwable is Exception)  {

    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: how do I declare DataWrapper class?

Comment: you can create DataWrapper class like

class DataWrapper<T>{
  var data:T? = null
  var error:Error?= null
  var isLoading:Boolean? = false
}